# getting a bot to recognise replies on discord

Tags: discord.py

Discord have added a feature allowing users to reply to each others messages. I can't find any referance in their documentation for a way of getting your bot to respond to replies.

Has anyone found a way?

Would it be possible to get a bot to print "reply made" in a channel each time users in that channel use the reply function on each others posts?

Comment: Since this discord update, there was no `discord.py` update so you probably can't do it at the moment.

Comment: it's not possible

Answer (score 1):

There is now a way to do this, using [message.reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message%20reference#discord.Message.reference).

Yes, I'm a bit late but it's here for anyone who searches this in the future.